# Cucumber 7: How to transform Data table into List<Map<String, List<String>>

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

Steps:

```
Then Check all manage cards domestic options and its credit limit get enabled
| Options_Name | isEnabled | isCreditLimitEnabled |
```

Do I need to create custom datatypes or can I convert by dataTable.asMaps(String.class,List.class)?

Comment: What's the example of your data and how would you expect it will look like in `List<Map<String, List<String>>`?

Comment: Example
| Options_Name | isEnabled | isCreditLimitEnabled |
| Online       | true | false |
| POS          | false | true |  
Expected Result: {POS=[false, true], Online=[true, false]}

Comment: @AlexeyR. with this I am getting the required result, But need to know other options for same. 
List<Map<String, String>> recordMapList = dataTable.rows(1).transpose().asMaps(); List<Map<String, List<String>>> newRecordMapList = new ArrayList<>(); Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>(); for (Map<String, String> record : recordMapList) { for (String strKey : record.keySet()) {List<String> list = map.computeIfAbsent(strKey, k -> new ArrayList<>()); list.add(record.get(strKey));}} newRecordMapList.add(map); 
Output: {POS=[false, true], Online=[true, false]}